# How to deal with files on an Amazon's EC2 web server?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ftp

Usually I would think **ftps**, but for *one* I'm having several troubles [configuring it](https://serverfault.com/questions/242068/awsec2-could-not-connect-ftp-client), and for *two* I'm wondering if there's a better way to transfer files in and out.

It's a basic web server that we decided to go with AWS for the load balancing and all amazing stuff we heard about how it can properly manage heavy loads. All we want here is a simple way to access the files within `/var/www/html` like FTP usually is (and later on add access to mysql).

I've set it up using the amazing [**CloudFormation**](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/) and the default **WordPress template** because we will have a blog (I've already managed to move the blog from root to `/blog`) and a database. That was simple enough. So we're running a weird Amazon RedHat 4.4 with no `iptables`. I believe vsftpd is already working just fine (after configuring it, also fairly simple). But then, not even [using the *pasv* tactics](http://linuxadminzone.com/install-and-configure-ftp-server-in-amazon-ec2-instance/) and opening the ports through *AWS EC2's Security Group* could I penetrate amazon's "firewall".

Right now I know I can transfer files using SSH and manually move & `sudo` permissions later on, since I can't and should not login as a root. But a more automated and simple way would be highly preferred.

How should we be accessing those files anyway? If it's *HTTPS* then it shall be, but then *why*?

If FTPS is the right way, can you please point a direction or a tutorial?

If by any chance it's using S3, all that would be new to me... So I'd also appreciate any pointers!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume ssh would be the way to go here. ssh is pretty much *the* standard.  Set your ownership to something like www:www, then scp or sftp with the client of your choice.

Comment: I'm already going this way for now. No idea why I haven't thought of it before... But I enjoyed even better Kyle's idea on using SVN! Would you happen to have any expertise to share on this?

Answer (score 3):

I would not use ftp(s) to transfer files, maybe its a personal thing but I think ftp is outdated, a pain to manage and setup.

Just use scp and manage your user/group permissions so you can write to that web folder. Or use something like svn to manage your files and better yet your revisions. A simple svn up is all you would need to do.

Since depending on your architecture, you will need to duplicate your htdocs folders across nodes if your actually planing on doing load balancing.

Comment: I believe the load balancing is already configured thanks to CloudFormation, but you gave a very nice idea on using some SVN... I do love GIT, but would you happen to know few options I'd have to go with in here? Wouldn't it also be troublesome to setup on EC2?